# Arrange the same column of each tibble in a list to a diagonal of a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am trying to create a list of matrix by extracting the same column in each tibble of a list to a diagonal matrix. Please help me to fix the error.

```
dat <- split(mtcars,list(mtcars$vs,mtcars$am,mtcars$carb))
dat2<-discard(dat,function(x) nrow(x)==0)
dat3<-lapply(dat2, function(x){
    diag(mpg)
})
```

The error I got was

> Error in diag(mpg) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Shouldn't `diag(mpg)` be `diag(x)` ?

Comment: what would your expected output look like? Maybe something like `lapply(dat2, function(x) diag(x$mpg))` ?

Comment: Ronak, you got it. Yes! That's the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to extract `mpg` column in `lapply`

```
lapply(dat2, function(x) diag(x$mpg))

#$`1.0.1`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 21.4  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.0 18.1  0.0
#[3,]  0.0  0.0 21.5

#$`1.1.1`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 22.8  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.0 32.4  0.0  0.0
#[3,]  0.0  0.0 33.9  0.0
#[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0 27.3

#....
```

---

Or `tidyverse` way using the new `group_split`

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_split(vs, carb, am) %>%
  map(~diag(.$mpg))
```